# Trouble with Reading STDIN

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read in integers through stdin using scanf however when I try to run my code it wants me to type in an integer instead of reading the line.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
scanf("%d", &x);
while (x != '\n') { 
   y += x;
   scanf("%d", &x);
}
```

Why won't my code read what's in stdin?

Comment: never newline is read to x.

Comment: Add `#include <stdio.h>` ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how it's crashing, but these lines:

```
scanf("%lld", &x);
while (x != '\n') { 
    ...
}
```

Will read a long integer into `x`, then execute the `while` loop unless the number you entered was 10 (ascii for `\n`). I'm pretty sure that's not what you wanted, but then it is hard to know what you did want.

Were you trying to loop until no number was input? If so perhaps check the return value from `scanf()`.

Note each call to `scanf()` is going to read a line.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `'\n'` is ASCII 10. ASCII 13 is the carriage return, `'\r'`. I think the OP's intention is to read any number of longs from a single line.

Comment: Also, scanf() is not *neccesarilly* going to read a line -- just until the next whitespace character. What this means is that `"1 2 3"` is read the same as `"1\n2 \t \n    3"`, so it will work for multiple integers on the same line.